# Google Calendar V3 API Push notification via java client

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I need subscribe for Google Calendar API v3 Push Notifications. I have checked documentation - it provides useful API details. I have checked [`java client`](https://google.github.io/google-api-java-client/releases/1.21.0/javadoc/index.html?index-all.html) library. It contains useful classes...

Trying:

```
com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar calendar = initObject();
...
calendar.calendarList().get("myMail@ukr.net").execute();
```

As result I have `CalendarListEntry` map with my calendar info.
Trying use same *calendarClient* object:

```
calendar.calendarList().watch(channel).execute();
```

in result:

```
17:46:26,540 ERROR # c.n.c.c.g.GoogleCalendarClient.watchCalendarList com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
```

It seems I have an authorization issue. I think I should not have one because of I can try one more time same `client` object and it returns correct result. Also I have considered case to use `optional` `token` field - no changes.

If someone needs my channel object:
    17:58:38,022 INFO  # {"address":"https://myPersonalVerifiedByGoogleAddr/google/calendars/","id":"4ac3e9e3-8428-405e-a8ed-6cf0e4fa25ff","payload":false,"type":"web_hook"}

```
address - my inet address verified by google
id - generated
payload - false (because of no content in my request)
type - web_hook (following google doc)
```

I have no ideas how to fix *unauthorized* in watch request, because of client is *authorized* (I would not be able to load calendar info).

Comment: You may want to try testing it by sending [http request](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20517294/5995040) to validate if it is just an OAuth token issue. Next is to validate if you have done all the required steps to [make a watch request](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push#making-watch-requests). This would narrow down the possible reasons you encounter the issue.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot `"reason": "push.webhookUrlUnauthorized"`. I have checked this issue in forum but answers do not help me. (My application is registered and verified, I have registered only `domain name`, trying push notifications i use `address` `domainName/google/calendars/`). no ssl certificates in my web (only google verification file to confirm my domain)...

Comment: @Mr.Rebot, Must I use SSL in my web (if i want to integrate google)?

Comment: I use [ngrok proxy](https://ngrok.com/docs). I hope it solves SSL issue.

Comment: I thinks so, in the docs it stated that "the Google Calendar API will be able to send notifications to this HTTPS address only if there is a valid SSL certificate installed on your web server."

Comment: @Mr.Rebot. It is solved using SSL workaround. if you'll add answer, I would mark it *ANSWERED*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try testing it by sending http request to validate if it is just an OAuth token issue. Next is to validate if you have done all the required steps to make a watch request. This would narrow down the possible reasons you encounter the issue.

Also check that in the docs it stated that "the Google Calendar API will be able to send notifications to this HTTPS address only if there is a valid SSL certificate installed on your web server."

Comment: I`ve got another question in this area, can you [check it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42738920/google-push-notifications-java-handler) please?