# Google push notifications java handler

Tags: java, push-notification, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I have subscribed my app to listen to Google push notifications. Channel details was persisted. I can receive notifications from google to my endpoint.

```
@PostMapping("/google/calendars/")
public void watch(HttpServletRequest request,
  @RequestHeader(value = "X-Goog-Channel-ID", required = false) String googleChannelId,
  @RequestHeader(value = "X-Goog-Channel-Token", required = false) String googleChannelToken,
  @RequestHeader(value = "X-Goog-Channel-Expiration", required = false) String googleChannelExpiration,
  @RequestHeader(value = "X-Goog-Resource-ID", required = false) String googleResourceId,
  @RequestHeader(value = "X-Goog-Resource-URI", required = false) String googleResourceUri,
  @RequestHeader(value = "X-Goog-Resource-State", required = false) String googleResourceState,
  @RequestHeader(value = "X-Goog-Message-Number", required = false) String googleMessageNumber,
```

Using information was received I can open `client` to google service. But I do not know how to get changes.

```
googleChannelId=354a78aa-0cc0-4b5b-96c5-e54e03a51e68
googleChannelToken=<null>
googleChannelExpiration=Sat, 18 Mar 2017 17:01:56 GMT
googleResourceId=eVHbdUeaWhfQPpvJPU7VZRxYzUs
googleResourceUri=https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/sergii_vlasiuk@ukr.net/events?maxResults=250&alt=json
googleResourceState=exists
googleMessageNumber=403802722
```

`exists` means `googleResourceId` was changed.

Using `googleChannelId` I load my channel details and open client.

---

1. **How to use `googleResourceId` in my pull change request (request example maybe)?**
2. Is it correct understanding: 
   `not_exists` means resource was deleted;
   `exists` means resource was created or edited?

---

#### Add details

I've tried

```
client.events().get(originalCalendarId, googleResourceId).execute()
```

Where:

1. `client` is `com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar` object with correct tokens.
2. `ginalCalendarId` - is good known google calendar Id, one was used in subscription.
3. `googleResourceId` - is from header message `X-Goog-Resource-ID` value.
   ->

   404 Not Found
   {
     "code" : 404,
     "errors" : [ {
       "domain" : "global",
       "message" : "Not Found",
       "reason" : "notFound"
     } ],
     "message" : "Not Found"
   }

Comment: "X-Goog-Resource-State" can have declared values: `sync`, `exists`.

Comment: May be I should use `etag` for mapping notification with changed data or google provides API for `X-Goog-Message-Number`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Google doesn't have a convenient approach to distinguish which exactly entities have been updated, I suppose we should think about a workaround. In my opinion, getting all the events and updating your database state by traversing and rewriting all the data will lead you to some performance issues.

To address that, I would choose using ***"etag"*** value that each event has. Every time an event is updated, the ETag changes(works in *CalDav* protocol)

http://cdn.nsoftware.com/help/IP9/cs/CalDAV_p_ETag.htm

If you save etag to your database with your event, then once you get the list of events from Google, you can just check etag value and update only the elements that were really changed. That must optimize the part when you update your entries.

Google supports etag. 
You can find it here:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

```
{
  "kind": "calendar#events",
  "etag": etag,
  "summary": string,
  "description": string,
  "updated": datetime,
  "timeZone": string,
  "accessRole": string,
  "defaultReminders": [
    {
      "method": string,
      "minutes": integer
    }
  ],
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "nextSyncToken": string,
  "items": [
    events Resource
  ]
}
```

**UPDATED:**

There is a more convenient way to perform synchronization. 
You can use Incremental synchronization approach. Incremental sync allows you to retrieve all the resources that have been modified since the last sync request.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync#initial_full_sync

You just need to save sync token every time you update data and use it in the request to get new data. In this case you will get only data that was modified.

```
Calendar.Events.List request = client.events().list("primary");
request.setSyncToken(syncToken);
```

If you call then:

```
events = request.execute();
List<Event> items = events.getItems();
```

You will get only the data that was updated.

Answer (score 2):

> But I do not know how to get changes.

The Google Calendar API provides push notifications that let you watch for changes to resources. You can use this feature to improve the performance of your application. It allows you to eliminate the extra network and compute costs involved with polling resources to determine if they have changed. Whenever a watched resource changes, the **Google Calendar API notifies your application**.

Once you have set up watch correctly your application will be informed when there has been a change.  You don't need to check for it.

**Example**

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/my_calendar@gmail.com/events/watch
Authorization: Bearer auth_token_for_current_user
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "id": "01234567-89ab-cdef-0123456789ab", // Your channel ID.
  "type": "web_hook",
  "address": "https://example.com/notifications", // Your receiving URL.
  ...
  "token": "target=myApp-myCalendarChannelDest", // (Optional) Your channel token.
  "expiration": 1426325213000 // (Optional) Your requested channel expiration time.
  }
}
```

There is a full article on how to set this up the documentation [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push)

**Note:**

This statement wont work because [Events.get](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get) requires an `event Id` as its second parameter not your GoogleResourceId

```
 client.events().get(originalCalendarId, googleResourceId).execute()
```

**How watch works:**

1. You decide you want to watch for changes on a users events.  You create a [watch on the events](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push#making-watch-requests).  Google returns to you resourceId this identifies the watch.
2. A change is made google sends you a [notification](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push#receiving-notifications) in the form of a HTTP Post.  It contains the resource id from your watch.
3. You know that the watch with this resource id is liked to a users events.  You use your refresh token to gain access to the users account. you do an [events list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) and scan though each of the events looking for which one has changes.

The resource Id can not be used to request events.  The watch does not tell you what exactly was changed or when.   You have to query the API to find that out.

Comment: @dimto, I have used this documentation, and I have no problems with receiving push notifications (see my example please). To provide you an example I have changed my google event, got an notification answer with resourceId (without event information). I know that I have used wrong API to get changes, but no more explanations for this case in google api, and this is reason why I have asked the questions. Right now I need to know **how to use resource id** to get google calendar changes (I have channelId, I have calendarId)!

Comment: I don't think I understand your question then.   You don't get the changes.   The changes are sent to you at the address you have supplied.  You don't need to poll the server for changes.

Comment: Ok, lets suggest you are right (I very need it)! Information that I published - I received if I changed google calendar event time. This information does not contains information about changed time, also I do not see here any link to the event. *May be I missed something? May be I have to listen not only header information? May be I should try one more request to get changes?* If you have done it before you should know what I have missed.

Comment: Try this update   Google only tells you something has changed its up to you to figure out what you should know by the resource id you created what type of watch it is and then be able to run the correct query on the correct user to figure out what has changed.

Comment: My channel listen to the calendar. If I get push notification, I can map notification to my channel information, I can build google client for correct user. But I confused if I have to load all events from Google for the calendar each notification catch time. I expected to have ability to pull changes for changed element only (event in my case). If I correctly understood your proposition is the same with my [`ugly answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42838062/5728095)

Comment: your channel is listing to changes to events on a calendar https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/watch   Yes you will have to request all of the events for the calendar each time you get a notification.  Google just tells you that there was a change in events it doesn't tell you which one.

Comment: yes, I have few test channels to listen to `calendar` space (event changes) and `calendarList` space (calendar changes). The question was `calendar` space only, to simplify understanding.

Comment: I have seen you have edited your answer, - checking one.

Comment: Simplify  isn't possible with this its confusing IMO.   I have edited it several times.   I have a meeting wont be back for a while give it a shot.  Let me know how it goes.

Comment: ...Nothing changed. **A change is made google sends you a notification in the form of a HTTP Post. It contains the resource id from your watch.**
*Should I use resourceId in my request? Where could I detect the resourceId (which object should contain one if I'm pulling info from Google)?*
**You know that the watch with this resource id is liked to a users events. You use your refresh token to gain access to the users account. you do an events list and scan though each of the events looking for which one has changes.**
*How I can detect, that my resourceId is liked to a users events?*